# jquery tooltip to display validator messages not changing back to invalid

Tags: jquery, validation

I have implemented the most popular solution from this article ([jquery tooltip to display validator messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381476/jquery-tooltip-to-display-validator-messages)) which for the most part is working brilliantly - unless you change the input after its been flagged as a success...

So here is what happens on form submission (with errors):
 1. Invalid fields correctly shown as error. good.

 2. enter text into field, div updates to include 'checked' class and image changes. good.

 3. remove the text in order to make it error again. still shows as success. BAD. 

Heres my code:
**JS File**

```
$.validator.setDefaults(
{
  invalidHandler: function(){
    toggleTopMessageBox('error')
  },
  submitHandler: function() { 
    toggleTopMessageBox()
    document.frmTransaction.hidSubmitForm.value='submit';
    document.frmTransaction.submit();
  },
  success: function(element) {
    $(element).addClass("checked");
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var container = $('<div />');
    container.addClass('inlineValidation');  // add a class to the wrapper        
    error.insertAfter(element);
    error.wrap(container);
    $("<div class='errorImage'></div>").insertAfter(error);   
  },           
  ignore: ":hidden:not(select)"
});
```

**CSS**

```
    div.inlineValidation {
position: relative !important; 
display: inline-block;
top: -2px;

}

div.inlineValidation:hover {
    z-index:1005; 
}

div.inlineValidation label {
  display: none !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.inlineValidation:hover label.error:not(.checked) {
    display: inline-block !important; 
    position: absolute;
    left:30px; 
    width:150; 
    padding:5px; 
    background-color: #E96D63; 
    border: 3px #E96D63 solid;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

label.error + div.errorImage {
  background:url("images/error_22x22.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  margin:4px;
  display:inline-block !important;
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label.checked + div.errorImage {
  background:url("images/success_22x22.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  margin:4px;
  display:inline-block !important;
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If I change the errorPlacement so that it only does something like

```
errorPlacement: function(error,element){
     error.insertAfter(element);
   },
```

then it behaves correctly, however of course I've lost the div formatting / wrapper. Have also tried adding something like `element.removeClass("checked")`  however this too does not seem to make a difference.

Tried to post some pics too which help, but I've got no rep being a newbie.

Anyway, thanks in advance for anyone who has any suggestions for me, much appreciated.

JP

Comment: where you have called 'element.removeClass("checked")'? try to call it on submitHandler.

Comment: Use `highlight`- http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight and `unhighlight`

Comment: @Bhushan - thanks for your response. I have tried adding the 'element.removeClass("checked") to errorPlacement in various places, have not tried submitHandler, will do so now

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - no luck unfortunately.

`submitHandler: function(element) { 
        toggleTopMessageBox()
        element.removeClass("checked");
        document.frmTransaction.hidSubmitForm.value='submit';
        document.frmTransaction.submit();
      },`

Comment: @shaunakde - cheers. Are you suggesting I essentially use the same functions, but within higlight and unhighlight, instead of success and errorPlacement?

Comment: Can't assure, but try it.